# ARM Toolchain 4.7 Defualt Config file

Tags: arm, toolchain

I want to define my own default compiler flags to avoid setting it in each Makefile at different levels. Is there any possibility if so how to do it ?

Comment: set them in the environment?

Comment: What do you mean by that ?